Using flink oracle cdc and reported an ERROR [ERROR] Could not execute SQL statement
I am using Flink sql client to commit a job by sql：
Flink SQL> create table products (
> id int,
> name string,
> primary key(id) not enforced
> ) with (
>      'connector'='oracle-cdc',
>      'hostname' = 'myip',
>      'port' = '1521',
>      'username' = '****',
>      'password' = '*****',
>      'database-name' = 'ORCLCDB',
>      'schema-name' = 'same as username',
>      'table-name' = 'products',
>      'debezium.database.pdb.name' = 'ORCLPDB',
>      'debezium.log.mining.strategy' = 'online_catalog',
>      'debezium.log.mining.continuous.mine' = 'true');
[INFO] Execute statement succeed.

Flink SQL> select * from products;


Flink version：1.18.0 
Flink cdc ：3.1.0 
Oracle：19c 

But it reports the following error:

[ERROR] Could not execute SQL statement. Reason:
org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.util.RestClientException: [Internal server error., <Exception on server side:
org.apache.flink.runtime.messages.FlinkJobNotFoundException: Could not find Flink job (ff05f7698f010bc7c171a58ca0b92415)

I turned on the archive log and did it as in this documentation.
How can I fix this issue?
